# how to get direction to nearest pin in mapkit

Tags: swift, mapkit

i'm trying to get direction to the nearest pin from the user current location

-My Code is

```
 let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
 var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let pins = mapView?.annotations
    // let currentLocation = mapView?.userLocation.location
    guard let currentLocation = locations.first else { return }
    currentCoordinate = currentLocation.coordinate
    let nearestPin: MKAnnotation? = pins!.reduce((CLLocationDistanceMax,nil)) { (nearest, pin) -> (CLLocationDistance, MKAnnotation) in
        let coord = pin.coordinate
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude)
        let distance = currentLocation.distance(from: loc)
        print(distance, pin)
        return distance < nearest.0 ? (distance, pin) : nearest as! (CLLocationDistance, MKAnnotation)
        } as AnyObject as? MKAnnotation
    if nearestPin?.title == "Test"{
        print("found")
    }
}
```

but it's not working as well

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you have set the Location Privacy in your `Info.plist`. In your case I check the authorization in an extension. 
**CLLocationManagerDelegate**

```
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    checkLocationAuthorization()
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate in the `viewDidLoad()`

**Delegate**
`locationManager.delegate = self`

Now on to the actual question. I created a private function which can be called in

```
 locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

**Search nearest annotation**

I guess you have an array of annotations declared (`var annotation = [MKAnnotation]()`). We will use these annotations (in my case Paris and Amsterdam) compared to our current location to find the closest.

```
    private func getNearestPin(locations: [CLLocation]) -> MKAnnotation? {

    let allPinsOnMap = mapView?.annotations

    guard let currentLocation = locations.first else { return nil }
    if let pins = allPinsOnMap {

        let nearestPin: (CLLocationDistance, MKAnnotation?) = pins.reduce((CLLocationDistanceMax,nil))
        { (nearest, pin) -> (CLLocationDistance, MKAnnotation?) in
            let coord = pin.coordinate
            let loc = CLLocation(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude)
            let distance = currentLocation.distance(from: loc)

            return distance < nearest.0 ? (distance, pin) : nearest
        }
        return nearestPin.1

    }
   return nil
}
```

The function will return an `MKAnnotation?` so when we call the function, we have to check if it doesn't return nil. We call this function in our extension!

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let nearest = getNearestPin(locations: locations) {
        if nearest.title == "Amsterdam" {
            print("Nearest is available: \(nearest.title! ?? "Title")")
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any further questions or feedback, please let me know!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help